# MatLab vs Python - Vectorizing and reshaping arrays

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

Consider three different MatLab arrays: `a`, `b` and `c`. All of them are equally sized arrays. Let's say, `64 x 64`. Now, in order to re-organize the elements of one of these arrays in form of a one-dimension vector inside another array, `X`, I can do the following:

```
X = [X a(:)];
```

Now, I have a `4096 x 1` array. If I want to have an array with that contains in each column the elements of different arrays, I can just repeat the process above for b and c.

Is there an equivalent of this in Python?

Comment: [`numpy.ndarray.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten) and [`numpy.ndarray.vstack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy-vstack)? And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323085/8944057) has a comparison of ways to flatten a 2D array in python.

Comment: size(a(:))` is (4096,1).  A column vector.  Not quite the same as a 1d numpy array.   `[a(:), b(:), c(:)]` will be (4096,3).  In `numpy` do you want (3, 4096) or (4096,3) array?  `numpy` is C ordered (by default), MATLAB F ordered.

Comment: I want a (4096,3) array. Thanks for the replies, they helped me solving my problem! I used np.vstack and that gave me an (3,4096) array. Then just got the tranpose of the resulting array and it worked! Thanks! 

X=np.vstack((X,Itmp.flatten(1)))
X=np.transpose(X)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.concatanate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function. Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.array([7,8,9])
res = np.concatenate([a,b,c])
```

It is also possible to do it sequentially as follows:

```
res = a
res = np.concatenate([res,b])
res = np.concatenate([res,c])
```

result:

```
res = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve 4x1, you can use `reshape()` function is this way:

```
np.reshape((-1, 1))

a = np.zeros((2,2)) #creates 2,2 matrix
print(a.shape) #2,2
print(a.reshape((-1, 1)) #4,1
```

This will make sure that you achieve 1 column in resulting array irrespective of the row elements which is set to **-1**.

As mentioned in the comment,  you can use numpy's `flatten()` function which make you matrix flat into a vector. E.g; if you have a 2x2 matrix, `flatten()` will make it to 1x4 vector.

```
a = np.zeros((2,2)) # creates 2,2 matrix

print(a.shape) # 2,2
print(a.flatten()) # 1,4
```